# Datagrid Tableadapter update method fails

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tableadapter

I dropped a table onto a XAML window then modified the code to use the roweditending event on the datagrid to update the local sql database.  It never works.   I won't add, update, or delete any records in the database tables.

## Here is the xaml code -

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource attenderTableViewSource}">
        <DataGrid x:Name="attenderTableDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,10,10,325" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" RowEditEnding="attenderTableDataGrid_RowEditEnding" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="first_NameColumn" Binding="{Binding First Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="First Name" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="last_NameColumn" Binding="{Binding Last Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Last Name" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="address_Line_1Column" Binding="{Binding Address Line 1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Address Line 1" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="address_Line_2Column" Binding="{Binding Address Line 2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Address Line 2" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="address_Line_3Column" Binding="{Binding Address Line 3, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Address Line 3" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="cityColumn" Binding="{Binding City, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="City" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="stateColumn" Binding="{Binding State, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="State" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="zipColumn" Binding="{Binding Zip, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Zip" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="telephoneColumn" Binding="{Binding Telephone, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Telephone" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="_Member_Column" Binding="{Binding Member?, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Member?" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="_Child_Column" Binding="{Binding Child?, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Child?" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
```

## Here is the cs code

```
namespace AttendanceRecPro
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
            private AttendanceRecPro.AttendanceRecProDataSet attendanceRecProDataSet = new AttendanceRecProDataSet();
        private AttendanceRecPro.AttendanceRecProDataSetTableAdapters.AttenderTableTableAdapter attendanceRecProDataSetAttenderTableTableAdapter = new AttendanceRecPro.AttendanceRecProDataSetTableAdapters.AttenderTableTableAdapter();
        private System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource attenderTableViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            AttendanceRecPro.AttendanceRecProDataSet attendanceRecProDataSet = ((AttendanceRecPro.AttendanceRecProDataSet)(this.FindResource("attendanceRecProDataSet")));
            // Load data into the table AttenderTable. You can modify this code as needed.
            attendanceRecProDataSetAttenderTableTableAdapter.Fill(attendanceRecProDataSet.AttenderTable);
            System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource attenderTableViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("attenderTableViewSource")));
            attenderTableViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();

        }

        private void attenderTableDataGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {

            if ( e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit )
            {

                try
                {
                    int rc = 0;

                    rc = attendanceRecProDataSetAttenderTableTableAdapter.Update(attendanceRecProDataSet.AttenderTable);

                    attendanceRecProDataSet.AcceptChanges();

                    MessageBox.Show("Return Code: " + rc);

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

                }

                MessageBox.Show("trying to update...");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

The return code is 0 so no rows are updated.  It never saves the data between runs.  I have also checked that the dataset properties are "do not copy" and have copied a version of the .mdf file into the bin/debug directory. I have spent almost a week look at this and do not see where I am missing something.  But no changes, added rows, or modified rows will update the database.  The grid doesn't give me an error, neither does the catch/try block.

Also, there is a primary key "AttenderID" on the "AttenderTable" in the database set as identity seed 1 increment 1 and set as primary key.  It should just auto-increment each time and I don't have an item on it because it shouldn't be touched by the user.  I don't believe this is a problem because the database should update it.

Please help with what event I should have the tableadapter update method in... Others use the RowEditEnding event and say they make it work but I can't figure out for the life of me how.

Comment: I moved the update to the SelectionChanged event of the datagrid and that works fine.  The changes to the datagrid have been updated in the dataset at this point and the .update method then carries those changes over to the database.  I also added the same code to the Window_Closing method so that it will update any last minute changes before the use leaves the program.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to move the .update method to the SelectionChanged event of the datagrid. See comment above.